# Are multi-part pokemon's parts interchangeable?

Tags: pokemon

After seeing a [question about how many pokemon can be seated in a pokeball](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157922/how-many-pok%c3%a9mon-can-a-pok%c3%a9-ball-keep-at-a-time), I had to ask myself if Exeggcute constitutes as a single pokemon or a "congregation of a single pokemon's parts", and if the parts are inseparable or can be swapped with other pokemon of the same type or similar.

- Has an Exeggcute ever lost one of its egg parts or swapped some eggs with another Exeggcute?
- Can one of the Dugtrio fall out of the band and get switched with a single Diglett?
- Can Shellders from a Slowbro detach and partner up with another Slowpoke?
- Can you accelerate a Mangemite to push out one of its kin from a Magneton and take its place?
- Can the gears of a Klinklang… you get the idea

Have there ever been any instances of combined pokemon separating or interchanging?

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. At least two of your examples are given as potential actions in the Pokédex. Such a splitting of parts seems to result in *devolution*.

> **[Slowbro](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Slowbro_(Pok%C3%A9mon))**
>
> *Lives lazily by the sea. **If the Shellder on its tail comes off, it becomes a Slowpoke again***.

[image]

> **[Exeggutor](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Exeggutor_(Pok%C3%A9mon))**
>
> *It is called "The Walking Jungle." **If a head grows too big, it falls off and becomes an Exeggcute.***

Comment: Does Shellder change its look back to a purple clam? Or am I misremembering how that evolution works

Comment: "a head falls off" implies a single egg will become a bunch of little eggs and that's called Exeggcute? Or does it become small and seek 5 more buddies to become a singular Exeggcute?

Comment: @user1306322 - I can't recall having seen it happen. We only really get a view of the Slowpoke in the comics.

Comment: @user1306322 - I think it goes looking for friends but again, I'm not sure.  Alt-Text: "*When the time comes, one of its three heads falls off. Before long, the fallen head grows into an Exeggcute.*"